# "View Search" in Oracle Developer tools extension for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, oracle-sqldeveloper

I feel odd asking a yes/no question on stack overflow but for the life of me no amount of googling will answer the question.

So when I'm in SQL Developer, I can type the beginning of a name of a view I want to check out and it'll show up:

[image]

But I cant seem to figure out how to do that in Oracle Developer Tools within VSCode:

[image]

Am I just plain out of luck? Is there a better interface? (within VSCode)  Is there a button I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view a description of an object with the VSCode Oracle Developer Tools extension, do the following:

1. Highlight something you want to describe
2. Right-click what you highlighted
3. Then, click "Go to Definition"

Note: If you want to describe a table, do not highlight the owner portion of a table name, or else you will get a message saying definition not found. Highlight only the table name after the period.